# Create a transparent demo screen for Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website on which i am adding new functionality and mandatory is that it is very crucial for user and user shall be notified about new button added on page and that too very clean.

So, i looked upon google and found `chardin.js` one of the solution. But

I want the page to be looked like as below

[image]

Any more solutions for this? If anyone has seen Flipkart solution then i will love that to be applied.

Comment: What's wrong with Chardin? What have you tried to solve your problem so far? Please post your attempts, relevant code, and describe the problem in more detail. Keep in mind that [Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool are off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You asked us to recommend a solution (aka, a tool), which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I provided a link to the FAQ in my previous comment, did you read it? You need to show some kind of attempt at solving the problem yourself, asking us to recommend a tool or library does not constitute a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is have a `<div>` with `position: fixed;`, `opacity: 0.5;` and `z-index: 10`.

The text can be added to this in form of `<p>`'s with `position: relative;`. Same goes for the image (`<img>`).

With Javascript, this `<div>` can be hidden once tapped/clicked.

You dont really need a plugin for this. Keep it simple :)

---

**Here is a working demo:**

(View it in Full Page mode.)

```js
document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#overlay{
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 10;
}

#circle1{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 30px;
}

#overlay p, #overlay img{
  position: relative;
}

#overlay p{
  color: blue;
}

#instruction1{
  top: 50px;
  left: 400px;
}

#arrow1{
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
}

#instruction2{
  top: 100px;
  left: 225px;
}

#dismiss{
  font-size: 12px;
}

main{
  z-index: 0;
}

main div{
  padding: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="circle1"></div>
  <p id="instruction1">This is some instruction.<br/>
    <span id="dismiss">(tap to dismiss)</span>
  </p>
  <img id="arrow1" src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/13/10/13/arrow-156792_640.png" />
  <p id="instruction2">This is something cool!</p>
</div>

<main>
  <div>This is my main content.</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Canu quote any example please?

Comment: @Gags For the lines that you need, I would suggest to make it in graphic editors like Photoshop and make a PNG image out of it and just include it in the overlay div.

Comment: @Gags I have added a sample image now so you get the idea. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: how can i highlight element on which arrow is pointing

Comment: @Gags You could add a circle image with that element in the middle.

Comment: i tried increasng Z-index.. can u edit fiddle pl

Comment: @Gags Check out the updated snippet. I have added it using some HTML and CSS. No image.

Comment: i want to keep it clean.. is not there any way i can bring this content as a n highlight

Comment: @Gags I am not sure how you want to highlight it. Do you have any example or graphical representation that will make it clear to me?

Comment: please check http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/ as they are higlihting button and image

Comment: @Gags I believe the easiest way to add those highlighting lines is to use an image. As far as changing the text color goes, you can add and remove classes with those colors appropriately.

Comment: yea that is fine.. but see they are displaying image and button above overlay// that is what i want to have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75474/discussion-between-gags-and-rahul-desai).

Comment: @Gags You can use a div of same size as the image with transparent background so it looks like that. ;)

Comment: Please check `https://jsfiddle.net/2e0dww6k/1/` .. i am not able to get

Comment: @Gags This should be posted as another question here on StackOverflow and give me the link to it here.

Comment: here gos the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695523/highlight-the-div-content-with-onscreen-guide