# Highlight the DIV content with onscreen guide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to highlight element on which arrow is pointing while using the onscreen guide for displaying instructions

here is the link for the fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e0dww6k/1/)

Some of code from fiddle is:

```
$("#overlay").on("click", function(){
  this.style.display = "none";
     $("#clk").show();
});

$("#clk").on("click", function(){
    $("#overlay").show(); 
    $("#clk").hide();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with `highlight` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak your styles a little bit to achieve this.

Add margin to your overlay `div` so the `main` is visible. Likewise, adjust the position of the arrow and the corresponding text to get it to an appropriate position.

Note that this solution wont work if the box is visually *inside* as in the `carmin` demo.

**[updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e0dww6k/3/)**

**Updated CSS:**

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#overlay{
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 120px;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#overlay p, #overlay img{
    position: relative;
}

#overlay p{
    color: blue;
}

#instruction1{
    top: 50px;
    left: 400px;
}

#arrow1{
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: 150px;
}

#instruction2{
    top: -10px;
    left: 225px;
}

#dismiss{
    font-size: 12px;
}
.shome{
    display: block;
}
main{
    z-index: 0;
}

main div{
    padding: 50px;
    background: rgb(0,120,170);color:#fff;
    z-index: 9999999;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: I did not want to highligh all div.. only "this is my main content" shall be higlighted

Comment: @Gags That I am not sure how to do it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you want. I have remove `this.style.display = "none";` from the overlay block. Now it is working.

```
$("#overlay").on("click",function(){
     $("#clk").show();
     // $("#overlay").hide(); //Add this line if you need same behaviour while click on overlay.
});

$("#clk").on("click", function(){
    $("#overlay").show(); 
    $("#clk").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Animating the element your mouse is on, can be done e.g. using .hover from jquery:

```
$("#maincont").hover(  
   function() {    
       $( this ).addClass( "hover" );  
   }, 
   function() {    
       $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );  }
);
```

Although at the moment your overlay div prevents the trigger to fire, because the maincont is "behind" the overlay.
It might be necessary to rethink the design.

EDIT:
Maybe it´s a better aproach to implement some kind of "at mouse position" tooltip mode, which can be activated and show the informations in a mouse-near info div.
Changing the mousecursor to

```
cursor: help;
```

CSS property would additionally help to difference between the two modes

Answer (score 1):

Didn`t understand what did u mean.
Maybe u just need to correct your styles,like this [fiddle](http://goo.gl/ewR5im)

Answer (score 1):

I have added a class glow to your div and add the same on the click and removed the same when overlay.

```js
$("#overlay").on("click", function(){
  this.style.display = "none";
     $("#clk").show();
    $("#maincont").removeClass("glow");
});

$("#clk").on("click", function(){
    $("#overlay").show(); 
    $("#maincont").addClass("glow");
    $("#clk").hide();
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#overlay{
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000;
    opacity:0.5;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#overlay p, #overlay img{
  position: relative;
}

#overlay p{
  color: blue;
}

#instruction1{
  top: 50px;
  left: 400px;
}

#arrow1{
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
}

#instruction2{
  top: 100px;
  left: 225px;
}

#dismiss{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.shome{
    display: block;
}
main{
  z-index: 0;
}

main div{
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgb(0,120,170);color:#fff;
     z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.glow{
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  position: relative;  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay" style="display:none">
  <p id="instruction1">This is some instruction.<br/>
    <span id="dismiss">(tap to dismiss)</span>
  </p>
  <img id="arrow1" src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/13/10/13/arrow-156792_640.png" />
  <p id="instruction2">This is something cool!</p>
</div>

<main>
  <div id="maincont">This is my main content.</div>
</main>

<br/>
  <div style="cursor:pointer;background:rgb(0,120,190);color:#fff;padding:10px;width:25%;text-align:center" id="clk">Click to see Instructions.</div>
```

> PS. Your image of the arrow is blocked in this snippet sorry for that

Comment: I did not want to highligh all div.. only "this is my main content" shall be higlighted